# How to return the result of a list in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, member

I have a list of items, which is in a method. I'm using another method to call out the list but I do not want to input the list inside that method. How can I solve this?

```
foo([a,b,c,d,e]).   
hi:- read(X),member(X,[a,b,c,d,e]).

?- hi.
|: a.
true.
```

I want to change the list in the go(X), using the foo(X) but it does not work. I know that foo(X) returns [a,b,c,d,e].

```
foo([a,b,c,d,e]).   
hi:- read(X),member(X,foo(X)).
```

k

Comment: Their are no methods in prolog, just predicates.

Answer (score 2):

first associate list with variable then use it in `member()`:

```
hi:- read(X),foo(Y), member(X,Y).
```

in Prolog rules do not return value. they checks(if variable has already associated with value or constant is passed) or associate(if variable passed has not been associated yet)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Was struggling in this section.

Comment: @kkbum, You can also pass the list as an argument to `hi`. Define `hi(List) :- read(X), member(X, List).`, and you can query the list before querying `hi`: `foo(List), hi(List)`. What way works best depends upon your use case.